# Need help seeding in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to rails and need help with seeding my tables. I have two tables "tracks" and "genres" and their migration files look like this

```
class CreateGenre < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :genres do |t|
      t.string :rock
      t.string :rap
      t.string :jazz
      t.string :alternative
      t.references :track, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateTracks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :tracks do |t|
      t.string :trackname
      t.string :artist

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And here are the models

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :genre
end
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Track
end
```

Right now when I go to psql and check my tracks table, it has two columns `trackname` and `artist`. And I want to add genres for the tracks too but i dont know how to do it?

I did this

```
data = [
  {
trackname: "hell yes",
artist: "beck"
    },
   {
trackname: "jailhouse rock",
artist: "elvis presley"
    }
]
```

I am having problem figuring out how to seed the genre too when i am doing this. Where would i put it? please help.

Comment: Something seems really off with that `Genre` table... how are you planning on using it?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your code I would try the following:

```
Track.create!(
  trackname: "hell yes",
  artist: "beck",
  genre_attributes: {
    rock: "true"
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to add `genre` to your `Tracks` table by running a migration.

Run:

```
rails generate migration add_column_to_tracks genre:string
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`.

That should add the new field to the database.